# Video Game design certifications

Tags: games

I realised that a designer has usually hard times getting into the video game industry without any previous experience on that. Sometimes having this previous experience is hard (developing a cool video game independently might requires more time that most of the people have available).
Therefore I was wondering if there is any certification program (even paid) that someone could do in order to get sort of "certified video game designer". Any ideas?

Comment: In the design industry, a portafolio is more valuable than a "paper".

Comment: why the downvote? Legitimate question if you're not in the industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portfolio is always more valuable than certification, but plenty of trade schools will provide training in these areas, and will come with a certification of some sort.

[Full Sail University](http://www.fullsail.edu) is one of the bigger players here.